# POSIX Shared Memory and msync

Tags: posix, shared-memory

I want to use POSIX Shared Memory and my question is about the usage of `msync()` and `munmap()` after calling `mmap(MAP_SHARED)`.

1. Are the changes made to the shared memory segment of one process visible to the shared memory segment of the other process without the use of `msync()`?
2. Are the changes made to the shared memory segment only visible in the file after `msync()`?
3. Are the changes saved when the shared memory segment is unmapped without the prior usage of `msync()`?

I have the impression `msync()` is only useful to apply the changes to underlying file and not to the shared memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**POSIX**

See [`msync(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msync.html):

- Implementation *may* decide that changes are not visible in other processes *and* in underlying file until `msync()` is called with `MS_ASYNC` or `MS_SYNC`.
- Implementation *may* decide that changes are dropped if `msync()` was not called before `close()`/`munmap()`.

This allows old implementations to use separate caches for memory mappings (a.k.a page cache) and file I/O (a.k.a buffer cache).

**Modern implementations**

Modern implementations (e.g. modern Linux) usually implement "unified virtual memory model" which uses the same cache for memory mappings and I/O. It's not required by POSIX or SUSv3.

In such implementations:

- Changes are visible in other processes and underlying file immediately.
- Changes are not dropped if `msync()` was not called before `close()`/`munmap()`.
- `MS_ASYNC` is a no-op.
- `MS_SYNC` is just like `fsync()`.

In Linux, `msync()` is just another interface to `fsync()` and nothing more. See [`msync(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html) manual page and [this thread](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-fsdevel/msg74493.html).

**Reference**

See "The Linux Programming Interface", section "49.4.4 Memory Protection and File Access Mode Interactions".